# Using php to display an image by passing to html img tag contains variables passed from php

Tags: php, html, image

I am passing an image link from PHP to be displayed on a HTML page. But, when the page is rendered, the image does not show, instead, a place holder is shown.

**PHP**

```
$details = getimagesize($config['thumb_dir'].$value['thumbName']);
if ($details !== false){
    $content.= "<h2>".$value['title']. "</h2>"."<p><img src= ".$config['thumb_dir'].$value['thumbName']." width =".$details[0]." height = ".$details[0] ." alt= ".$value['filename'] ." /></p>";
```

**HTML output**

```
<h2>Welcome to the Home page</h2><h2>Title for image 1</h2>
<p>
    <img src= /home/rraja01/public_www/w1fma/thumbs/thumb-landscape-large.jpg width = 150 height = 150 alt= landscape-large.jpg />
</p>
```

Comment: what is the pages extension is it .php or .html if the later then it wont work it need to be named .php etc just as you mentioned "on a HTML page" ?

Comment: also could you show the output of the html page as in the code onto the result your using?

Comment: Please, don't put spaces between your HTML attributes name and value.  
You should also escape characters: `<img src=\"".$config['thumb_dir'].$value['thumbName']."\"/>`

Comment: the src tag in your html output must have double quotes around the path.  try putting escaped quotes around the php variable.

Comment: @SimonDavies The PHP code wouldn't be parsed and executed in an HTML page. This is a valid PHP file since everything is output correctly.

Comment: @JeffNoel Actually this works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/e6L4T/ not really a best practice though... :P

Comment: @MarkusKottländer I know it works, but as you said it's not the best thing to do. If OP ever gets to write within an older DOCTYPE he'll have some nasty surprises.

Comment: @JeffNoel i know that i wanted to make sure that was not the mistake in the first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$config['thumb_dir']` variable is returning the full path on the server and including /home/rraja01/public_www/ at the front -- very few servers have the root mapped to the website.  You may need to do something like this:

```
$website_path = substr($config['thumb_dir'], 24);
$content.= "<h2>".$value['title']. "</h2>".'<p><img src="'.$website_path.$value['thumbName'].'" width="'.$details[0].'" height="'.$details[0].'" alt="'.$value['filename'].'" /></p>';
```

Comment: below is what i am putting into the $config: $config['app_dir'] = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$config['upload_dir'] = $config['app_dir'] . '/uploads/';
$config['template_dir'] = $config['app_dir'] . '/template/';
$config['view_dir'] = $config['app_dir'] . '/views/';
$config['thumb_dir'] = $config['app_dir'] . '/thumbs/';

Comment: dirname returns the path to the file, which I presume is actually `__FILE__` -- there's no need to do it twice and when you echo it out to the browser, it's giving too much of a path... you only want the path relative to the domain, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the relative path of your image (relative to the document root):

```
$details = getimagesize($config['thumb_dir'].$value['thumbName']);

$relative_path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $config['thumb_dir']);

if ($details !== false) {
    $content .= '<h2>'.$value['title'].'</h2>'
             .  '<p><img src="'.$relative_path.$value['thumbName'].'" width="'.$details[0].'" height="'.$details[0].'" alt="'.$value['filename'].'" /></p>';
}
```